# How to use a class argument in another class in Java

Tags: java, class, arguments

First I will mention that I am a beginner programmer and trying to learn.
In short my problem looks like this: I have 3 classes (main, author, book)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Author a=new Author();
    Book b=new Book();
    //creating author
    a.setName("Paulo Coelho", "PC@gmail.com");
    System.out.println("Author : " + a.getName() + "\ne-mail: "+ a.getEmail());
    //creating book
    b.setName("Alchimist");
    b.setYear(2010);
    b.setPrice(15.7);

}
public class Author {
    public static String name;
    public static String email;
    public static void setName(String n, String e){
        name=n;
        email=e;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }


public class Book {
    String name;
    int year;
    double price;
    Author a;


    public void setName(String b){
        name=b;
    }
    public void setYear(int y){
        year=y;
    }
    public void setPrice(double p){
        price=p;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public String getBookDetails(){
        ?????????????
    }
}
```

How can I make the connection between author and book so as when I set the book details they are linked to the first created author and
when I print my getDetails I get the details for the right book  ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).

Comment: create set method to set the author details in Book class.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a property `Author a;` in your `Book` class.

You need to add a setter for the the authos in the `Book` class so that you can set it from your `main` method:

```
 // in Book class
 public void setAuthor(Author author){
      this.a = author; 
 }
```

---

```
 // in main:
 b.setAuthor(a);
 b.setName("Alchimist");
```

after that you can access  the properties of the assigned author in your method `getBookDetails()`.

---

## BTW

In Java the length of identifier names names is virtually unlimited. There is no penalty in any way for long identifier names. So don't be stingy with letters when choosing names. Eg. in your example use *always* `author` instead of `a` and `book` instead of `b`. This will make your life easier in the long run...